# Error para editar un registro en Symfony

Tags: symfony3, symfony, dql

Tengo una relación entre 2 tablas `Orders` y `Users` y se muestra la información correctamente.

Mapping Users:

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Users:
type: entity
table: users
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        column: ID
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    username:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    yourname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    firstname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    lastname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    middlename:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
    address:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
    address2:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
    apartment:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    pobox:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    city:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    state:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    zipcode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 100
        options:
            fixed: false
    country:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    countrycode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 2
        options:
            fixed: false
    phone:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    fax:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    email:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    password:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    company:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    type:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 0
    datein:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Mapping Orders:

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
type: entity
table: orders
indexes:
    fk_order_user1_idx:
        columns:
            - user_id
id:
    orderid:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        column: OrderID
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    orderdate:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        column: OrderDate
    ordernumber:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: OrderNumber
    customername:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 250
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CustomerName
    customeraddress:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CustomerAddress
    countrycode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 2
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CountryCode
    shippingaddress:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingAddress
    status:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: Status
    subtotal:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: SubTotal
    shippingcost:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: ShippingCost
    tax:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: Tax
    discount:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: Discount
    totalorder:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: TotalOrder
    shippingcarrier:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingCarrier
    shippingtype:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingType
    shippingtrackingnumber:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingTrackingNumber
    paymentmethod:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: PaymentMethod
    paymentapproval:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 100
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: PaymentApproval
    cc:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 20
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CC
    ccexp:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CCExp
    ccv:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CCV
    memo:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: Memo
    sessionid:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: SessionID
    discountcode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: DiscountCode
    hasshipgift:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
        column: HasShipGift
    message:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 300
        options:
            fixed: false
    imagen:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        options:
            unsigned: false
    siteType:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: site_type
    shippingname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 250
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingName
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            user_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Necesito editar un registro de orders por lo que coloco en el listado el siguiente código:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{path('edit_orderlist',{ 'id': ordenes.orderid })}}">Edit</a></td>
```

Pero al momento que llega al controlador que tengo con este código:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $orders_repo=$em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Orders");
    $order=$orders_repo->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

Me muestra este error:

> Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "BackendBundle\Entity\Users"

`Orders` tiene como clave primaria `OrderId` y Users como clave primaria `id`

¿Alguna idea para solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar y leer las diferentes recomendaciones, el problema estaba en los archivos .yml de las tablas y en las Entidades, además que encontré este error a pesar de que en pantalla el listado se veía bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para verificar esto cree un ambiente de pruebas y realice la importación y creación de entidades para revisar si existía algún error.

Así quedo el código:

```
//BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
type: entity
table: orders
indexes:
    fk_Orders_Users_idx:
        columns:
            - Users_ID
......
manyToOne:
    users:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            Users_ID:
                referencedColumnName: ID
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

`Users.orm.yml` quedo igual que antes

Otro cambio esta en la Entidad `Orders.php`

```
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
private $users;
.........
/**
 * Set users
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Users $users
 *
 * @return Orders
 */
public function setUsers(\BackendBundle\Entity\Users $users = null)
{
    $this->users = $users;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
```

Con estos cambios todo funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Hola juanitourquiza asegurate que en tus archivos doctrine xml tengas algo como esto:

AuthBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Marcacion.orm.yml

```
Usuarios\AuthBundle\Entity\Marcacion:
type: entity
table: marcacion
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
```

y en el archivo: AuthBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\metadata\orm\Marcacion.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Marcacion" table="marcacion">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
```

en ambos archivos debe indicar que el id es IDENTITY.

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta. Agregue el mapeo en yml que tengo en las tablas Users y Orders. No utilizo el archivo .xml , voy a revisar lo que indicas.